# How to store all previous checkbox value in array in visual c++ using c++

Tags: visual-c++

I am new to programming in visual c++.I am using c++ codings.I have datagridview control in visual c++ .In that if checkbox is checked ,the values are stored in boolean arrays in another class.In Run time after select the checkbox ,then i select the button, it draws triangles based on the how many checkbox selectd.I want to keep the previously selected checkboxe values if next time i open the form.how can i do that.Please anybody help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're keeping the boolean array already in another class, one that doesn't go away when the form is closed? Good. When you re-open the form, you are re-initializing the state of the checkboxes. Don't set them all to "unchecked"; read the initial state from the boolean array instead.

Comment: Thank you very much.I follow the method you mentioned.It works well.